# setElementData() on link element

Tags: webforms, 10

How do I call `setElementData()` on a link element? The following code doesn't work.

```php
$submission->setElementData('link_element', ['title' => 'string', 'url' => 'string']);
```

I get this error message.

> Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given in Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionStorage->saveData() (line 1316 of modules/contrib/webform/src/WebformSubmissionStorage.php).

When I look at the link element in the webform, the title is *text field* and the URL is *URL*. I assume that the URL should be the URL object.

This code does not work either.

```php
$url = Url::fromUri('base:/admin/structure/webform/manage/my_form/submission/' . $webform_submission->id());
$submission->setElementData('link_element', ['title' => 'string', 'url' => $url]);
```

This code avoids the error, but it doesn't set the element.

```php
$text_and_url = Url::fromUri('base:/admin/structure/webform/manage/my_form/submission/' . $webform_submission->id());
$url = Link::fromTextAndUrl('string', $text_and_url);
$submission->setElementData('element_link', $url);
```

For a link element that is limited, the code works fine.

```
$url = Url::fromUri('base:/admin/structure/webform/manage/my_form/submission/' . $webform_submission->id())->toString();
$nomination_submission->setElementData('nominee_submission_link_limited', ['title' => 'string', 'url' => $url]);
```

The *toString()* method is probably redundant.

On a text element, the code works fine.

```php
$submission->setElementData('textfield_element', 'string');
```

Comment: Have you tried passing a [`Url`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x) object for the url param?

Comment: Yes, I'll update the ticket to indicate.